# Emissive Material Acting Strange

Tags: emission

I've assigned an emissive material to parts of an object in a scene. The rendered view inside the viewport looks fine but the final render doesn't. Somehow, the emissive material goes beyond the faces I've assigned the material to - and only in my renders.

I've attached stills to illustrate the problem. I've checked everything but I don't know what's wrong.

Thanks.[image: Rendered Mode inside Viewport]

[image: Rendered Image]

Comment: Do you use Subdivision surface? It could be, that your rendered SubD settings are higher than the viewport one

Comment: Great ! That was it :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Your welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever render and viewport results are different, check for:

- different settings in modifiers for viewport and render
- hidden objects, collections, lights
- sampling settings
- collection settings (e.g. holdout, indirect only)
- renderlayer settings